# Quote path part of URL but not parameters

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I have an URL of the following form `https://website.com/chill & relax/folder/file.txt?a=1&b=2` (The link is an dummy example, it's not meant to be working)

When I paste this URL in Firefox, I can fetch the wanted `file.txt`, but when I try to retrieve the file using python and requests, it doesn't work:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "https://website.com/chill & relax/folder/file.txt?a=1&b=2"
>>> requests.get(url)

Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00982B70>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] [...]
```

How come Firefox can request the file but not `requests`? How can I replace the spaces and "&" signs only in the path part of my URL?

EDIT: I now believe that requests can actually perform a requests with URLs that contain spaces. I think this issue is linked to my proxy, Firefox can work with my proxy, but requests commands executed within PyCharm are stopped by my proxy.

Comment: Use https://www.urlencoder.io/python/ to URL encode your address (but not the parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For path encoding you can use this:

```
from requests.utils import requote_uri
url = requote_uri("https://website.com/chill & relax/folder/file.txt?a=1&b=2")
```

But link anyway not working for me even in browser. Does the link is actually valid?

Comment: The link is an dummy example, it's not meant to be working, I'll edit my original message to explain this. Thanks for requote_uri, I'll look into that.

Answer (score -2):

Simply URL encode your path then append the parameters.

```py
import urllib.parse
url = urllib.parse.quote("https://website.com/chill & relax/folder/file.txt")
url += "?a=1&b=2"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: This sets `url` to `'https%3A//website.com/chill%20%26%20relax/folder/file.txt?a=1&b=2'`, which is also not going to work.

Comment: Can you post more of the traceback? I think the error might be explained more there, since the docs say `requests` auto-escapes spaces

Comment: urllib.parse.quote encodes too much characters. Plus how do you remove the params part of the URL? I create my URL by reading data from a file, I don't set the path and params manually

Comment: @JammyDodger I am not the OP. Clearly `'https%3A//website.com/chill%20%26%20relax/folder/file.txt?a=1&b=2'` is not a valid URL.